# Why didn't the Avengers simply jump 5 years back?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-motivation, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, the Avengers decided to

> jump back to 2012 New York because they could find three Infinity Stones there.

Why didn't they simply jump back 5 years just before Thanos destroyed the Infinity Stones? This way they could get all six Infinity Stones at once.

Comment: Because Thanos had them.

Comment: @OrangeDog - *"Excuse me, Mr. Thanos, sir. Can we have the Infinity Stones so we can kill you, please? What do you mean **'No'"**?*

Comment: So basically you are asking why [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_nG6DVay5U) didn't happen in the movie.

Comment: Similarly, they could have just gone back in time to right before the snap, then tell Thor to aim for the arm, not the chest.

Comment: To be fair Tony invented the technology they used, what he says goes and he didn't want to lose his daughter. Think about it, would you take the flux capacitor out of the DeLorean? You're going to do what the science man wants!

Comment: @E_McAndrew What exactly do you mean in the context of the question?

Comment: I mean that Tony didn't want to jump back 5 years, if you were one of the other Avengers would you go messing around with his invention?

Answer (score 37):

They need to get the Infinity Stones before Thanos has even ***one*** of them because there's absolutely no way in hell that he's going to hand them over, let alone taking him on when he's *expecting a fight* and has all six(!).

Don't forget what Banner said to Strange

> **Bruce Banner:** *No telling. **He has the Power and Space Stones, that already makes him the strongest creature in the whole universe.** If he gets his hands, on all six Stones, Tony...*

and what Maw said to Thanos

> **Ebony Maw:** *My humble personage… bows before your grandeur. **No other being has ever had the might, nay the nobility, to wield not one, but two Infinity Stones. The universe lies within your grasp.***

It's important to note that Thanos (in Infinity War) was basically holding back for the entire film, at least until the very end. He's only really trying to get the stones and has little or no interest in killing those who're opposing him.

Comment: "They need to get the Infinity Stones before Thanos has even one of them because there's absolutely no way in hell that he's going to hand them over, let alone taking him on when he's expecting a fight and has all six(!)." ~> And yet, Avengers were ready to confront Thanos after Thanos used the Gauntlet second time. They had decided to die trying, together. The question has `character-motivation` tag.

Comment: @iloveyou3000 That's out of sheer despair. Why bother to deal with a top notch Thanos for acquiring the stones if there's a way to avoid that?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking - Also, what other choice did they have? If he'd been at full power and in possession of the stones and wanting to defend himself, he'd have been completely unstoppable. The only way they were able to defeat him was because he was crippled and stoneless

Comment: @ILoveYou3000 “Avengers were ready to confront Thanos after Thanos used the Gauntlet second time” — with Captain Marvel, and peak-condition Thor. Against Thanos alone on a planet, with no satellites, no army, just him. *Little* bit different to re-entering the Battle of Wakanda and trying to safely extract him from Thor’s axe-y embrace.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Not to forget about not meeting their other selves while doing so...

Comment: Just throwing this out there but Ebony Maw wasn't exactly correct when he claimed Thanos was the first to wield 2 infinity stones.  Loki simultaneously wielded the scepter (mind stone) and the tesseract (space stone)

Comment: @user1 - He had them in their energy-reducing enclosures. Not the same thing

Comment: @Valorum There's no indication in the MCU that the Tesseract or scepter did anything to reduce the energy of the stones. They merely harnessed their power much like a certain shiny glove.

Comment: *"...when an inferior species makes direct contact with the Stones, they’re ripped apart by the sheer force of the thing. It’s a glorious and frightening sight. In order to protect these beings, the Stones were given defensive casings: the Orb for the Power Stone, the Scepter for the Mind Stone, the Tesseract for the Space Stone, the Eye of Agamotto for the Time Stone, and”—his voice hardened—“as you know, the Aether for the Reality Stone.”"* - [Infinity War: The Cosmic Quest Vol.1](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/The_Cosmic_Quest_Volume_One:_Beginning)

Comment: "*The Stone was placed in the Orb, as a means of controlling its raw and dangerous energy. Fate only knows how long that will last. As one who was witness to just a fraction of a fraction of its abilities firsthand, I can say with certainty that the force within the Stone cannot be contained for long.”*

Comment: @user1 - So the stated intent of the casings isn't just to hide the stones, it's to modify and control their energy.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Apparently meeting your former self isn't actually that big a deal in the MCU.  Both Cap and Nebula did so without annihilating the universe.  Also Tony and Bruce to a lesser extent in that they were within eyeshot of their past selves if not directly interacting with them.

Comment: @Valorum 1. You're using comic book sources to make a point about events in the MCU. 2. In comics the soul gems, as they were originally called, were brought to our universe by an unnamed celestial who committed suicide which resulted in the scattering of the gems, making him the first being to wield more than 1 infinity stone. 3.Even if I accept that the vessels containing the stones restrict their power then I don't see how the gauntlet is any different, which makes Thanos' 'wielding' of 2 infinity stones no different than Loki holding the Tesseract in one hand and the Scepter in the other.

Comment: @user1 - For your reference, the Cosmic Quest prequel prose novels are considered to be canon to the rest of the MCU (by those who care about such things).

Answer (score 2):

One possible answer is that they were never planning on having to deal with Thanos again. Remember, Thanos came to the present sort of by accident. It wasn't exactly part of their plan. Their plan was to snap everybody back, not necessarily fight Thanos for the gauntlet. Fighting Thanos was kind of just a consequence of their actions.

If they went back to any time when Thanos had them, they were gonna have to fight him for it again. It's not like he was just gonna hand them over so they could snap everybody back again. And, if they lost (again), they'd be back where they started, maybe worse. Much safer, and more likely to be successful, is the idea of going to a time where he didn't have them all. Then they wouldn't have to work as hard for the stones themselves, and they could snap everybody back no problem.

Comment: They litteraly went to fight him 3 week after the first snap, knowing for sure that he still have the stones and the gantlet and that he might have an army with him.

Comment: This plan was conceived 5 years later though. I'd think they would have had much cooler heads on them then. If half the universe had just been erased you'd be pretty mad about it, 5 years down the line you're concentrating on trying to bring them back, not get revenge. Also when they went to fight Thanos on that planet they had nothing to lose.